# Dockerfile: COPY does not work (even tho he can find the file)

Tags: docker, dockerfile, containers

I am trying to build a docker image.

I want to pull files from gitlab and copy them to another directory.

Here is the relevant part of my Dockerfile:

```
ENV RALPH_LOCAL_DIR="/var/local/ralph"
ENV RALPH_IMAGE_TMP_DIR="/tmp"

RUN mkdir -p $RALPH_LOCAL_DIR
RUN cd $RALPH_LOCAL_DIR
WORKDIR $RALPH_LOCAL_DIR
RUN git clone <OMITTED_FOR_THIS_POST>
WORKDIR project-ralph/ralph

COPY README.md $RALPH_IMAGE_TMP_DIR/
```

I get this error:

```
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder094767244/README.md: no such file or directory
```

So the copying fails. But I can list the file in the container with ls. So if I run `RUN ls -la README.md` he can find the file. So why can't he copy the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`COPY` copies the file from the host system.  You need to run `git clone` there, before you start running Docker operations.  (This also simplifies the case where you need credentials of some sort to run `git clone`: getting an ssh private key into an image to run `git clone`, without leaking it into the final image, is kind of tricky, and you don't really want to be doing kind of tricky things with ssh keys.)

```sh
FROM ...
WORKDIR /var/local/ralph
COPY README.md .
```

```sh
git clone <OMITTED_FOR_THIS_POST>
docker build -t ... .
```

If the file is already in the image, as in your existing `Dockerfile`, then you need to `RUN cp` or `RUN mv` to put it somewhere else.

```sh
RUN cp README.md /tmp
```